# How to send files to archive in SharePoint?

Tags: workflow

I want to archive old documents.

**For example :**

There are Modified Date , Modified By , Name columns. If Modified Date is not TODAY, and if it is called "EXPIRED" , I want to send these files to archive.

Is it possible with SharePoint?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick search on the site for "archive documents" gives tens of results which should answer to your question. Please have a look at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=archive+documents